# Pass a parameter into a class that implements IMappingAction

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I am using and implementing the [IMappingAction](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html#using-imappingaction) interface but I need to pass a parameter when using it.
Is that something that I can do ?

```
public class AfterMapAction : IMappingAction<SourceClass, DestinationClass>
{
    public void Process(
        SourceClass source,
        DestinationClass destination,
        ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destination.Name = PassedParameterName
    }
}

CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
                .AfterMap<AfterMapAction>(); //<== Where do I pass the parameter
```

Comment: The same as [here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper) or through DI somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ResolutionContext` to pass parameter (`name-value` pair) to `AfterMap` action function.

The approach will be as:

```
// AfterMap Action function that usages context
public class AfterMapAction : IMappingAction<Source, Destination>
{
    public void Process(Source source, Destination destination, 
                                       ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destination.Name = context.Items["YourVal"].ToString();
    }
}


//Configuration declaration
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
      .AfterMap<AfterMapAction>();
});

var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();    

//Pass actual parameter value e.g. "ActualName" 
var result = mapper.Map<Source, Destination>(source, opt => 
                       opt.Items["YourVal"] = "ActualName");

// The result will have Name as "ActualName".
```

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are like contracts, so whatever is defined in the interface, it must be implemented in the class, so, if the interface doesn't have a method definition with a parameter in it, then you can not enter a parameter in there.

That is if you don't want to break your contract obligations, of course, in which case, the law officer (the compiler) has something to say...